# Mapping over a piecewise function

Tags: list-manipulation, piecewise, map

This is a followup to [a question I posted earlier today](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/identifying-maximal-element-in-a-list-with-case-distinctions). Suppose you have a piecewise function such as "snap=max[x,0]= x if x>0, 0 otherwise".

Then you would think that it must be straightworward to apply a function to this, i.e. to obtain "f[x] if x > 0, f[0] otherwise".

My intuition is that I should be able to say "f[snap]", but this doesn't work. The best I can do (after [help from AccidentalFourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183037/identifying-maximal-element-in-a-list-with-case-distinctions)) is quite complicated:

```
snap = PiecewiseExpand[Max[0, x]]
MapAt[f[#] &, Map[MapAt[f[#] &, 1], snap, {2}], -1]
```

This produces the desired result, but it seems strange that I need to do this. Is there a more straight-forward solution?

Comment: Why not use `Ramp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pwMap1[f_] := MapAt[f, #, {{1, All, 1}, {2}}] &;
pwMap1[f]@snap // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  f(x) & x>0 \\
>  f(0) & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Also:

```
pwMap2[f_] := Internal`ToPiecewise[#, f /@ #2] & @@ Internal`FromPiecewise[#] &;

pwMap2[f]@snap == pwMap1[f]@snap
```

> True

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks, I've learned a lot from this!

Comment: @Christoph, thank you for the accept.